# Adicionar linha em branco Excel usando VBA

Tags: vba

Tenho uma planilha com 10k linhas, nesse formato (exemplo):

```
3004977 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  2   \%D \^ S

3004972 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  3   \%D 
3004972 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  2   \%D 
3004972 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  2   \%D 
3004972 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  2   \%D 
3004972 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  1   \%D \^ S

3004967 \{DOWN} \{TAB 9}    REMESSAS    \%S 18082017    \{TAB}  110 \%D \^ S
```

A cada mudança na coluna A existe uma linha em branco. Mas preciso inserir mais 3, em todas. Com o código abaixo, que achei no SOen, ele só adiciona na primeira:

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("a1")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Pelo que entendi sempre terá uma linha entre os dados e você precisa de três linhas? Se for isso creio que macro abaixo te ajudará!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se desta forma te atende:

```
Sub AdicionaLinhaBranco()

Dim COLUNA_VERIFICAR As String
Dim ULTIMA_LINHA As Integer
Dim QTD_LINHAS As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

COLUNA_VERIFICAR = "A"
QTD_LINHAS = 2
ULTIMA_LINHA =     ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Range(COLUNA_VERIFICAR & "1").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Row < ULTIMA_LINHA

    If ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        For i = 1 To QTD_LINHAS
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next i
        ActiveCell.Offset(QTD_LINHAS + 1).Select
        ULTIMA_LINHA = ULTIMA_LINHA + QTD_LINHAS
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Boa sorte e sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Com algumas pequenas alterações consegui...

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("a1")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then

    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

    iRow = iRow + 4

Else
    iRow = iRow + 1

End If

'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""

'
End Sub
```